# In SQL, how to prevent duplicate values for a user in a table, not for a whole table?

Tags: sql

I would like to create a table with T-SQL. User is a foreign key from a users table. One user can't have two same phone numbers in 'phone1' and 'phone2' fields. However, it is allowed that two users have the same phone number. How do I create such field, to be unique only for the same userid foreign key?

English is not my strong side. I know it works for all rows. I need it only to work with rows that have the same userid foreign key. So I heard that my design could be improved by making check constrained and making foreign key a primary key or to normalize a table adding a table for phone numbers.

Let's say there is a 'users' table and this would be 'contacts' table. So in contacts userid is foreign key and can be imported more then once.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    -- ...
)

CREATE TABLE Contacts
(
    ContactId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    UserId    int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY FK_Users_Contacts REFERENCES Users ( UserId )
    Phone1    varchar(20),
    Phone2    varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Or in other words, in any given row, `Phone1 <> Phone2`, right?

Comment: Does your SQL implementation support `CHECK CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: Yes. However there could be also two rows for the same foreign key, the same user.  Like in phonebook, you add first time phone1 and then second time you add phone2. Yes, it supports 'check', it's t-sql.

Comment: Tip: change that table’s primary key to be a composite key that includes the `UserId` - or make it a simultaneous single foreign and primary key?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, can one user be on multiple rows?

Comment: Yes. In one record there could be phone1=123 and phone2=null and in a second record this must not be possible phone2 = 123.

Comment: I don't quite understand but you could probably do this with a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. If you edit your question and add sample data it will be easier to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll want a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE [tableName]
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DiffPhones CHECK ( Phone1 <> Phone2 )
```

The syntax for your specific DBMS may differ.

That said, I think your table design can be improved. You should normalize Phone Numbers to their own table.

Comment: Not all databases support constraints, OP did not specify which DB he is using

Comment: This would be for one row. Is it possible to make it for every row with this foreign key ?

Comment: No a table constraint works for all rows. Read up on it

Comment: English is not my strong side. I know it works for all rows. I need it only to work with rows that have the same userid foreign key. So I heard that my design could be improved by making check constrained and making foreign key a primary key or to normalize a table adding a table for phone numbers.

Comment: @HrvojeT Why does your table have multiple `UserId` values? Why doesn't it have a `UNIQUE INDEX` constraint on `UserId`? What is the business-case for allowing multiple rows for the same user?

Comment: Let's say there is a 'users' table and this would be 'contacts' table. So in contacts userid is foreign key and can be imported more then once.

Answer (score 3):

you should have one userid row with phone 1 and phone 2 value in one record than this check constraint works correctly. First time user enter a value in phone 1 it will create a new record and second time instead of creating another record for Phone 2, it will update that first record which has phone 1 value and if phone 1 and phone 2 is same value then it will give an error because of that check constraint.